# Is the following Statement always True?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ be a series such that $a_n\to 0$. Suppose that for any $ n\geq 1$ we have that $a_n = \frac{1}{2^{k_n}}$, where $k_n$ is some positive integer. Then the series is **always** convergent. Is the statement True or Flase?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I will surely go through it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try
$$ \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} +\frac{1}{2^2} +\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^3} +\frac{1}{2^3} +\frac{1}{2^3} +\frac{1}{2^3} +\frac{1}{2^3} +\frac{1}{2^3} +\frac{1}{2^3} +\frac{1}{2^3} + \ldots$$

Comment: hey, thanks for the response. I will attempt using your hint.

Comment: hey, could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Two of $1/2^1$ makes $1$; four of $1/2^2$ makes $1$; eight of $1/2^3$ makes $1$; ...

Comment: So can I say $k_n$ a sequence for n≥1. $(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3.....)$ (4 is repeated 16 times and so on). so $k_n \to \infty$. so $\frac{1}{2^{k_n}} \to 0 $. evetually giving a infinte divergent sum. Could clarify that taking  a sequence $k_n$  = (1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3.....) is to prove that infinite sum is divergent?

Answer (score 1):

**False**. Take $k_n = \log_2  n > 0, \forall n \ge 2\implies a_n = 2^{-k_n} = 2^{-\log_2 n} = \dfrac{1}{n} \to 0$. But $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n  = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n} = \infty$  i.e divergent !

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I will go through your solution.

Comment: Hey, I'm curious how did you interpret "$k_n$ is some positive integer". Because suppose for n = 3, $k_3 = log_2 3 = 1.584963$. which is not an integer value.

Comment: @GaurangChauhan: You are indeed right. Let me find another expression for $k_n$. But at least we know it's false !

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple counterexample: take $k_n = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I thought of that too. So basically I would be adding $\frac{1}{2}$ infinite times. so , eventually getting : $1+1+1+1+.....$ but taken $k_n = 1$ as $a_n =\frac{1}{2^{k_n}} = \frac{1}{2}$. $a_n \to  =  \frac{1}{2}$, which is ≠  $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread your post. Then the answer above suffices.